# R - regular expression

Tags: regex, r

I would like to list all files in a directory that have "xyz" at the beginning and the first underscore has a 2 after it.

For example, `xyzfjd_2_34_1.png`, `xyz-39_2dog.jpg` would work, whereas `xyzdog_3_dog.png` would not work.

I tried

```
list.files(dir, pattern="^xyz*_2*");
```

which is clearly wrong, mostly because I don't even know what I'm doing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do file names without an underscore match? I am assuming no.

I think you are interpreting `*` for any character. Instead, `.` is any character. `*` is "0 or more times". So your pattern `^xyz*_2*` can match `xy_` and `xyzzzz_222`. It won't match `xyz1_2`.

Try:

```
list.files(dir, pattern = "^xyz[^_]*_2")
```

- `^` Beginning of the file name
- `xyz`
- `[^_]*` Any combination of characters that is not `_` (including the empty string)
- `_2`, an underscore followed by a two.

I don't worry about the rest of the name because  the pattern only needs to match part of the file name.